# After implementing C3P0 the page keeps refreshing

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

I am trying to implement C3P0 into my hibernate. I have as follows:

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://IPaddress</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>  
  <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
  <!--<property name="connection.pool_size">20</property>-->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">1000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">864000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod">30</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.initialPoolSize">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize">100</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize">10</property>
  <!-- SQL dialect -->
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
  <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
  <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <!-- Mappings -->
  <mapping class="com.nebuilder.ats.pojo.TopicsDetails"/>
  <mapping class="com.nebuilder.ats.pojo.GroupsDetails"/>
  <mapping class="com.nebuilder.ats.pojo.ModulesDetails"/>
  <mapping class="com.nebuilder.ats.pojo.TraineesDetails"/>
  <mapping class="com.nebuilder.ats.pojo.ColoursDetails"/>
  <mapping class="com.nebuilder.ats.pojo.CustomersDetails"/>
  <mapping class="com.nebuilder.ats.dao.MusicStoreDaoImpl"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<beans>
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.url}"
          p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}"
          p:connectionProperties="${jdbc.connectionProperties}"/>

    <!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc) -->

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction manager for a single Hibernate SessionFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory"/>
        </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Both of the files are in my resources folder. They seem to be working, but the problem is that my page keeps loading or refreshing without displaying any information when I try to access the database.

I am using jars as follow - hibernate-c3p0 3.6.3.Final, hibernate-core 3.6.3.Final, c3p0 0.9.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to debug your application to see where is the problem ?
Moreover, it seems to be a little bit excessive to define a timeout of 864 000 ms, isn't it ?

Comment: I changed the timeout to 10 and idle_test_period to 10, still the page keeps loading forever.

Comment: Can you paste the part of your code which is accessing the database ?